# What is the font used in the $x$ in the following image?

Tags: fonts

What is the font used in the $x$ in the following image? I have tried many possibilities but cannot reproduce it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You want to know in order to avoid it, don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that was used `\pmb` command (stands for "poor man bold") defined in the `amsmath` package. Instead of it I suggest to use `bm` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$n(\pmb x) = \frac{d\pmb x}{ds}$ \qquad $n(\bm{x}) = \frac{d\bm{x}}{ds}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's obviously just a bunch of normal `x`'s overlapped together.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\def\weirdx{x\text{\llap{\raisebox{0.5pt}{$x$}}\llap{\raisebox{0.4pt}{$x$}\hspace{0.5pt}}}}
$n(\weirdx) = \frac{d\weirdx}{ds}$

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Although you may want to consider using normal bold italic letter: [Math Expression in bold italic - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573882/math-expression-in-bold-italic)

Comment: you've loaded amsmath so \pmb is available, no need to define another:-)